# Listing all references in a python method

Tags: python

I have classes like these

```py
class Test:
    def __str__(self):
        return "Test"

class Test1(Test):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Test1"

class Test2(Test):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Test2"

class Runner:
    pass

class Runner1(Runner):
    def run(self):
        print("I'm a method, doing this and that")
        print(f"And I use {Test1()}")

class Runner2(Runner):
    def func2(self):
        print("I'm a method, doing this and that")
        test = Test2()
        print(f"And I use {test}")
```

and I would like to discover all `Runner` classes, which use `Test` instances, like this:

```py
for klass, func, ref in get_all_references(Runner):
    if isinstance(ref, Test):
        print(f"{klass.__name}.{func.__name} uses Test!")
```

That is, I'm looking for the `get_all_references` method, which returns all referenced objects of any classes of type `Runner` (and their methods), which I can inspect for class type/inheritance.

The motivation behind this is to discover all places (class/method names) where instances of `Test` are used.
I think part of the problem is solved by static analyzers/doc creators/cross reference builders, but I couldn't find any which could be used to get this information via an API.

Comment: you somehow want, from the outside, to get the variables inide the funciton scope to test them for type/inheritance? Sounds unlikely.

Comment: I don't think this will be possible, because a function does not contain any references to local variables *until it is called* (a function object has references to parameter names and default arguments, but it sounds like this is not what you want).

Comment: Can you add more context of what problem you think you can solve with such a function?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you *actually trying to accomplish*. This would require something like introspecting the function. Perhaps just checking for global references would suffice, since it seems like you are only interested in calls to global classes?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I've updated the description in the hope it will be clearer. I think I was quite misleading in that I wrote this in one chunk, however I don't need this information inside the program, so a static analyzer is also OK.

Comment: Yeaaaaa you can't really do this in general in Python without actually running the function. Note, even static analysers would require fully and accurately type-annotated code.

Answer (score 0):

i think `gc` module has several useful functions in that matter, but it sounds like [`gc.get_referrers()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers) is what you need.

Comment: Sorry, updated the description, so hopefully it's now clearer. BTW, thanks for the idea, this also useful in some cases!